# XIB and Storyboard automatically offests my views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uistoryboard

This is a really strange problem. When I'm building my UI in XIB (or just a custom table view cell in the Storyboard) and drag a view inside a container, and set that view's X and Y to 10, for some reason, the rendered view is thrown off screen. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Strange, right? The label's x = 10 and y = 10 are definitely within the bounds of that container view (a `UITableViewCell`, this is an XIB) but as you can see, it's off the screen. How can I fix this? I've already tried restarting Xcode. It was working properly just last night.

Comment: Have you tried changing the origin to the top left corner and then entering (10,10) for the coords?

Comment: Write that as an answer. Fixed my problem. I must have dragged that red cross-arrow by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch your origin to the top left corner and then re-enter (10,10) for your coords.

Glad this fixed it!

Comment: I am amazed that this doesn't happen to more people. I don't know why they let you change the origin in IB like that, but (as the OP discovered) you can sure confuse the heck out of yourself if you do.

Comment: Yeah. Really weird that that's even configurable.